# Blazor WASM is not picking up the culture from my browser

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

We have an issue where Blazor is always thinking its culture is en-US. This is despite it running on my local machine which is en-GB and my local browser which is also set to UK.

Why is it not picking up the culture?

```
<td class="col">@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name</td>
```

Outputs

> en-US

We are using blazor in wasm mode in .net 8

Answer (score 0):

en-US is the standard culture Blazor is using as you may have already guessed.

You need to retrieve the users culture by using JSInterop on page load (OnInitializedAsync) and set the currentCulture of Blazor using the response.

Here is a code snippet for the js code at least:

```js
var language;
if (window.navigator.languages) {
    language = window.navigator.languages[0];
} else {
    language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
}

console.log(language)
```

```
Program.cs

builder.Services.AddLocalization();

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .AddSupportedCultures(new[] { "en-US", "es-CL" })
    .AddSupportedUICultures(new[] { "en-US", "es-CL" }));
```

Comment: Why on earth does it not do that automatically? The documentation does not appear to mention having to use JSInterop to get the culture. (Unless I missed it)

Comment: The doc sadly only tells you the current culture of the server which is set by default or configured by you.

Comment: The server is my machine which is set to en-GB...

Comment: So I have tried the above javascript and it returns en-US.... Why on earth is it doing that? I am using Chrome.

Comment: Right.... So it seems that when Visual Studio opens Chrome, it opens with a different language set than my normal chrome window...

Comment: You said the server is set to en-GB. So I want to make sure you did it like the doc says and configured your program cs like I edited in above?